# IE8 :after not working with jQuery selector

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I was attempting to use `:last-child` with IE8, but after reading several threads about this here, determined, it's just not happening 'bub. So - I went the next best route, which was using jQuery to append on the `last-child` class with CSS, doing the following:

```
$('.section-header > span:last-child').addClass('last-child');
```

which does add the appropriate class in IE8. But, when I go to style that, it does not seem to be working. This is apparent in a few places on the site, [located here](http://zslabs.com/sample/cofc/) (compared to an actual decent browser like Chrome):

- Top-nav, not removing last `border-right` property on `<li>` items
- `#top-grid` not adding in arrows (using `:before` and `:after`)
- `.section-header` not applying `padding-left` I have specified for both `:last-child` or `.last-child` (done with jQuery)
- Calendar, not adding in top border color to selected tabs

So - there's obviously quite a few areas of inconsistencies - I'm not really looking for a "here's how you fix every single one individually", more a "here's a concept your missing about IE8". I've already tried declaring a doctype (another thread had mentioned that), but after a few hours, you begin to drive yourself crazy :) I really would appreciate any nudges in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Selectivizr, it should add the last-child, among other things, to IE6-8 http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: @Rick Calder: IE8 is known to have issues with `:last-child:after` even with Selectivizr :(

Comment: damn... did not know that. Oh well, I qualified it with "should" at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're grouping both your `:last-child` and `.last-child` selectors in the same rule sets. This causes IE8 to ignore the entire rule set because of the `:last-child` part, meaning it'll ignore your `.last-child` part as well.

Since you're using jQuery to add the class anyway, you may as well remove the `:last-child` part of your selector and have it work in all browsers.

Or if you want browsers with scripting disabled to see your `:last-child` rule, you have to split up the selectors and duplicate your style rules for each selector.

Comment: Wow - that was exactly the issue. Very good to know for the future (and by future, I mean until IE8 dies a slow painful death). Thank you very much!

Comment: Other browsers generally behave the same when they encounter unsupported selectors, as it's all part of the spec. This includes prefixes. Be careful!